# Is the direct object pronoun « le {it} » allowed to refer to a subsequent idea?

Tags: pronoms

I wrote in an email:

> Il lui coûterait sans doute de **l**’avouer, mais ***sa maîtrise de la cuisine japonaise est assez médiocre***...

I haven’t given it much thought until now, but I wonder if the direct object pronoun « le {it} » can be used to refer to an idea that is only introduced later in the sentence?

The « le » in this sentence refers to the part after the « mais ». Is this usage allowed? I mean, compared to when « le {it} » refers to a preceding idea:

> ***Sa maîtrise de la cuisine japonaise est assez médiocre***, il lui coûterait sans doute de **l**’avouer.

---

The English equivalent would be:

> I haven't realised **this** until now, but ***tomorrow is Christmas Eve***!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... If you're saying "can I say that ?" the answer is yes because I see nothing wrong in the French you wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this construction is correct as long as the reader/listener is able to quickly understand what is behind the pronoun.

What is referred to is called the *antecedent* which is somewhat paradoxical because etymologically it means it is located before, not after.

There is a grammatical term to specify this particular case, it is a *[cataphore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphore_(grammaire))*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a correct construction.
But it is preferable to introduce the idea in the same sentence (like you did in fact).